# PayPal buy now button with IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am new to `PHP` , and `PayPal`.

I need to do crowdfunding site.

Here I have a form where user can choose pay method :

1. Pay with terminal
2. Bank transfer
3. Paypal

Input with amount that user want to donate for project, and some fields like name, surname , phone etc.

Now action of my form is `example.com/pay.php`, here I  register pay in my database with status "in progress" and i want after it to redirect user to PayPal page.

How to redirect user to PayPal with necessary data (see in PayPal button code) , after I add the transaction to my database?

Code of of my PayPal button:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="BJKELCPG5WDSN">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="MD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Help African child">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2299">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="67.00">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/test/thanks.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/test/">
                    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/test/listener.php">
                    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to     pay online!">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
```

Help me please with this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i changed questions, sorry for that